# Assembly.GetTypes() throwing an exception

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

What does assembly `GetTypes()` do behind the scenes? Assuming an assembly has been loaded to the `AppDomain` does it still need to read from the physical DLL? And what the assembly manifest do?

Iterating through the assembly like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
```

I'm occasionally getting the following error:

```
 Could not load file or assembly
```

Which tells me that because an assembly is loaded into the `AppDomain` it's not necessarily fully loaded to memory. Sometimes it still needs to go back to the file.

My questions:

1. Why is it doing that?
2. What can I do to detect these semi-loaded assemblies?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Getting a type from a assembly may require additional assemblies to be loaded so that is most probably the reason for the error; a failure to load a dependent assembly. However a .NET assembly may be constructed from several modules in different files so I believe you may also face this problem if you have a [multifile assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/168k2ah5.aspx) and one or more of the files are missing or corrupt.

Associated with the error you should get more information about the specific assembly that could not be loaded.

If you just want to load a list of the loadable types in the assembly you can use a extension method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetLoadableTypes(this Assembly assembly)
{
    if (assembly == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(assembly));
    try
    {
        return assembly.GetTypes();
    }
    catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
    {
        return e.Types.Where(t => t != null);
    }
}
```

(Source: [Get All Types in an Assembly](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/23/get-all-types-in-an-assembly.aspx))

Comment: This doesn't work for Core dlls loaded into the classic .net runtime. You can load but can't browse for types.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij *"Core dlls loaded into the classic .net runtime"* is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Behind the scenes, GetType method returns the address stored in the specified object's type object pointer member (When the object is stored in the heap, this information is stored along with couple of others like Sync Block Index). This is how the GetType method returns the true type of any object. An assembly might be dependent on some other assembly that must be loaded. And unless it is required by the application, it won't be loaded by JIT. So, yes, it requires the assemblies to be physically available at all times.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old, but leaving a note here that `GetTypes` might throw an exception if the application has not loaded the assembly dependencies especially in the newer .NET Core/.NET 5/6 .dlls.

Microsoft has introduced`{assemblyName}.deps.json` file which contains dependencies for an assembly, so you will need to load those too before you can call `GetTypes` without getting an exception.
I found these blog posts to be helpful on how to do that:

- https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2020/01/using-typegettype-with-net-core.html
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support#load-plugins