# Load all types from all assembly in project

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to search all types that belong to a spesific to all assembly referenced by my project

What I have done , load all assemblies in my project by this :

```
var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();
var loadedPaths = loadedAssemblies.Select(a => a.Location).ToArray();

 var referencedPaths = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.dll");
                var toLoad = referencedPaths.Where(r => !loadedPaths.Contains(r, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
                toLoad.ForEach(path => loadedAssemblies.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path))));
```

And then search for specific types

```
const string @namespace = "name space to search"

 var   types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
                .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == @namespace );
```

now when I try to iterate over the types , I get a loader exception 
"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows"

and system.windows is not an assembly refrenced by my project

EDIT :

The exception is throw when doing the following

foreach (var type in types)
{
}

Comment: I don’t understand. Where do you get the error? Show your stack trace.

Comment: @poke - that is quite standard error (asked many times already) when some of assemblies have references that can't be resolved. Call stack would not be helpful for general version of question as each case is specific to particular set of DLLs. And stack for LINQ based iteration is mostly useless - one need to do manual `foreach` with try/catch to get useful info with skip logic.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I’m asking mostly because I have no idea in which part of OP’s code the error occurs.

Comment: @poke see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915389/assembly-gettypes-throwing-an-exception

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov , what I dont understand . in my types linq query I specify the namespace , why is then types from other namespaces also returned

Comment: @Shachaf.Gortler which part of `SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())` from your point of view performs filtering by namespace?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov there is a where clause there as well

Comment: But Where will be executed *after* `GetTypes` that throws the exception.

Comment: The GetTypes does not throw the exception I will edit my question for more clarification

Comment: This is totally different question than (and not related to exception you see) - LINQ queries are lazy and indeed you'll *see* exception when query is actually executed (i.e. on `ToList` or when starting `foreach` like in your case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I ended up during it , the reason why it was failing is the directory of my dll held , more dll than was referenced directly by my project .

```
var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();

loadedAssemblies.SelectMany(x => x.GetReferencedAssemblies())
                .Distinct()
                .Where(y => loadedAssemblies.Any((a) => a.FullName == y.FullName) == false)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(x => loadedAssemblies.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(x)));
```